# Articles don't have titles

Tags: bug, status-completed, collectives, articles

Right now Articles don't have titles.

Unless the writer of the article adds a summary in the first few lines of the articles it is impossible to see what the article is all about without opening it.

Please add a title to Article posts so they can be more easily inspected.

---

It seems that Articles do have titles, but they are not visible due to a bug.

[image]

Comment: I haven't even been able to figure out how to *open* an article...

Comment: @CodyGray Click on the comments... I reported a bug https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408775/4267244

Comment: Wait, they did have titles before. This was probably introduced while fixing another bug.

Comment: It feels more like the Community user removed the title accidentally while editing it, because I can see the title there in the revisions and also the anchor / heading tags for the title is also present, just that it is empty.

Comment: Oh, that's actually possible, @Abdul. Considering that [the title isn't shown in the edit interface](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68104924/edit), the submission of the edit was probably interpreted by the system as removing the title. That's... another bug. Who's counting?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Not the Community user though; it's [whoever the anonymous user who edited the question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29268683). Still a bug though.

Comment: You approved that edit, @Cody. Oh, what have you done [again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404710/how-did-a-moderator-manage-to-break-this-question-by-trying-to-close-it/404714#comment821039_404714)! :P

Comment: Oh, so it looks like edits are put under the Community users name. Although I cannot find the edit button (the link given by @CodyGray above works) for some reason, or is it that you have to join the collective to see the edit button?

Comment: Hold on, so anyone can edit an article, but the edit link is hidden? That's some awful UX/UI design right there if allowing edits is intentional xd

Comment: At the very same edit page there is also [a (probably deleted?) comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwzfr.png) which [isn't shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuYnZ.png) below the article in normal view. And it appears to be from a suspended user?

Comment: @Abdul Edits by anonymous users are always put under the Community user's name. That's not new. The main site works the same way.

Comment: I don't know what I did the last time, @41686d6564. *This* time, I'm just trying out the great new feature that the Stack Overflow team launched this week!

Comment: So far it's only one. I wonder when it will become articles. As for the behavior, it seems there is a lot of auto-recognition going on.

Comment: @janw That user somehow managed to join both collectives, too: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114/jeremy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out! We've been able to find the bug and fix it. Opening an Article should be easier now as well ;).