# The Community user is a Recognized Member? Why?

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-user, collectives, articles

I just noticed that an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/) on the Google Cloud collective was "edited by
Community ♦" (i.e., a suggested edit from an anonymous user was approved). To my surprise, I saw the "Recognized by Google Cloud" label attached to its user card:

[image: Community user's user card]

I can't see how/why the Community user should be a Recognized Member. Is this a bug?

Comment: Do you not recognize the Community member? I wouldn't forget that face anywhere.

Comment: Yea, we don't need a third party "endorsing" SE's default user... That's weird.

Comment: @CodyGray You might've met him (or her?) [at an event](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot?userid=-1). Unfortunately, I haven't had that chance yet ;)

Comment: How does an anonymous user suggest an edit to begin with? I'm not seeing an edit button anywhere. The revision history also doesn't show a rollback or edit button, which seems indicate that edits from non-recognized users is not possible? Going manually to the edit page does work however. Wonder if that's intentional...

Comment: @Ivar Anonymous users have the ability to suggest edits on regular posts. As to the missing edit button on the article, see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408776/articles-dont-have-title#comment851685_408776).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out! We've been able to find the bug and fix it. This should not happen anymore.

Comment: What, exactly, was fixed?

Comment: There was a way for users that do not have the right permissions to edit the post. This is not possible anymore

Comment: Now that it's been fixed, how was it possible to edit the article without the permissions? I'm just curious.

Comment: Maybe the Community user edits the posts via direct SQL updates, which wasn't expected.

Comment: @10Rep the permissions for articles are slightly different from questions and answers but at the end of the day they are all posts. The problem came from that direction.

Answer (score 28):

It's slightly worse than that: *anyone* who edits an article is recognized.

[image: Screenshot showing me as being a recognized editor of the article after editing]

As far as I can tell, this is only a UI bug on the article itself. I have not been silently upgraded to a recognized member, so it's just a display problem on articles. I assume it's related to how unrecognized members weren't supposed to edit in the first place.

Comment: _"I assume it's related to how unrecognized members weren't supposed to edit in the first place"_ Yeah, that does seem to be the core issue. One thing to note is that regardless of the label, you're _not_ listed as a Recognized Member [on the "Members" tab](https://i.imgur.com/YzOZpQ0.png) (but that's probably due to the fact that you're not a member to begin with).

Comment: "I can't find any indicators that I've been silently upgraded to a recognized member" - and I made myself a member before the second edit

Comment: Not buggy at all...